# Rails render_to_string with partial that requires a form builder object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render-to-string

I feel like this is something simple and I'm completely missing it..

I have an edit.html.erb file that has something akin to this in it;

```
<%= form_for @some_object, html: { autocomplete: "off" } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

the `_form.html.erb` file it is referencing has something akin to this in it;

```
<%= f.fields_for :some_nested_object, @some_object.some_nested_object.order(:sort_order) do |obj| %>
    foobarbaz form stuff..
<% end %>
```

**I can't change the edit or the form partial**. They are required as is by a large portion of the site.. it is what it is, and I'm stuck with that.

I want to be able to render the form partial with the `f.fields_for` to string in a json result.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { html: render_to_string('/path/to/_form.html.erb',
                                                        layout: false,
                                                        locals: { f: ????????? }
  end
end
```

But, I am not sure how to assign `f` in this case.

I feel like it should be something akin to

```
locals: { f: ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper::form_for(@some_object) }
```

or something like that but that obviously doesn't work.

This feels like this should be simple, and I'm just an idiot..

Thoughts?  (about the question, not my being an idiot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, behold the hacky hack:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|

    format.json do
      form_builder = view_context.form_for(@some_object) { |builder| break builder }

      html = render_to_string(
        '/path/to/_form.html.erb',
        layout: false,
        locals: { f: form_builder }
      )
      render json: { html: html } 
    end
  end
end
```

That being answered (assuming it's actually working) note that this is a hack. This is not a way we should be writing code (even though we sometimes have to) and the next step is to figure out why are we in the situation when we have to do such a hackery.

For example, is there any chance you are re-inventing [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem?

Comment: So Max gave me the idea and you have said the same thing..  I wish he hadnt deleted his comment I'd have given him the +1..  I hadnt thought to use vew_context and that works perfectly as you show.. Thanks

Comment: Also just a general commentary, sometimes we are thrust into legacy code that we have to write stuff for and have no control over..  This is one of those cases.. Using `view_context.form_for(@some_object) { |f| @formBuilder = f }` and then `{f: @formBuilder}` worked and solved the issue.  Not a clean solve for sure.. but a whole code base refactor is beyond the scope of the project at this time (thought it REALLY needs it)

Comment: I salvaged my answer but not sure if `f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new('object_name', object, view_context, {})` is less hacky.

Comment: Update: This actually doesn't work.  There is some weird bug where the partial renders perfectly in place normally, but when you use this method above (all of them) any time you do a `<%= whatever %>` in the code it causes hanging `&lt;/div&gt;` in the output even though there are no open divs or anything like that.  It almost feels like a bug in the form builder helper..

Comment: @JasonEllis Is the output of `wahtever` html_safe?

Comment: Yes that's not the issue.  If you add <%= "" %> to the end of the form the closing divs at top don't render..  And the error showing is whatever the html after the last %> which is just a bug.. something buggy in the rails code I'm pretty sure.. We had a bunch of sr. developers all looking at it scratching their heads..

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of [ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-c-new):

```
def index
  f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(
     'object_name', # the scope for the inputs
     object,        # object wrapped by the form builder
     view_context,  # the template where the form builder can call the tag helpers on 
     {}             # options
  )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      html = render_to_string(
               '/path/to/_form.html.erb',
               layout: false,
               locals: { f: f }
             )
      render json: { html: html } 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that.. it's complaining that its missing block.. 
```
Missing block
Extracted source (around line #431):
#429       #   <% end %>
#430       def form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
*431         raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
```
How do I pass the black in that case?

Comment: I would guess just like with any other Ruby method - `view_context.form_for(@some_object) {}` or `view_context.form_for(@some_object) do; end`

Comment: So I tried both `{}` and `do;end` and they both error at the first `f.fields_for` with this error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `fields_for' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x0000000116b1d598>):`. I don't even know what the safe buffer is hah

Comment: I deleted my answer since I jumped the gun and didn't think about the fact that `form_for` -   `form_with` of course return strings. Salvaged through an edit.

Comment: Well thank you, you gave me the answer with the view_context method which I didn't think about at all.. thanks for that.